# Manga where a boy was trapped in a cave and becomes best at archery cultivation

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I'm looking for a manga I read a year or so ago. It is about a boy(mc) who was trapped in a cave by his grandfather and a wolf was added every day. The boy was taught wolf steps I think it was called.

He becomes the best at archery cultivation to prove that archery cultivation is better than sword cultivation. He became so good that he could shoot a bow without arrows. Later he entered a cave and learned the best sword cultivation techniques in the world. The manga is more on the realistic side when looking at the art. Ancient times.

Comment: When was "a while ago?"  Where did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the art, or how the protagonist was portrayed?

Comment: https://forum.novelupdates.com/threads/mc-using-archery-in-cultivation.80207/

Comment: what is "archery cultivation"?

Comment: @Basya - https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tags/cultivation

Comment: Possibly one of these; https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tags/archery?

Comment: @Valorum - thanks.  I had no clue!

Comment: @Basya - Every day is a school day on SFF:SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe Bowblade spirit? It fits the description.

### Wolf Steps

[image: Wolf Steps]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you [edit] in some more information about this work to show how it matches the details of the question?

Comment: Sorry for the ugly image insert. I'm posting from my phone, which doesn't have very good image editing capabilities.

Comment: Thank you everyone.